# How to translate this objc block to Swift closure?

Tags: objective-c, swift, syntax

Objective-C:

```
    [BmobUser signOrLoginInbackgroundWithMobilePhoneNumber:mobilePhoneNumber andSMSCode:smsCode block:^(BmobUser *user, NSError *error) {

       .........
     }];
```

And I wrote this in Swift:

```
    BmobUser.signOrLoginInbackgroundWithMobilePhoneNumber(phoneNumber, andSMSCode: smsCode, block: {(_user: BmobUser, error: NSError) -> () in


      ........
    })
```

But I get the compiler warning saying "Cannot invoke ... with an argument list of type ..."

So what is the correct syntax of closure like this in swift? Thanks

Comment: Sure you need `andSMSCode:`? But note that this is not a code translation service site.

Comment: Yes. It is prompted automatically. I guess there is something wrong with the closure.

Comment: It looks fine to me. You can change `signOrLogin/*....*/ block: {(_user, error) -> () in }` to just `signOrLogin(number, andSMSCode: code) { (user, error) -> () in }`. If the closure is the trailing parameter, you can supply it outside of the func itself.

Comment: But after doing this I cannot access to the method  or property of user and error. Is there any way to set user to a specific class?

Comment: Try this BmobUser.signOrLoginInbackgroundWithMobilePhoneNumber(phoneNumber, andSMSCode: smsCode, block: {(_user: BmobUser, error: NSError) -> (Void) in


      ........
    })